# Unreliable NEST Rest API

Tags: nest-api

Right after oauthing wiht auth token, I make few api calls.
 The problem is that the responses are unreliable in the sense that, at times some of the requests work as expected and at other times they don't and there is no deterministic way to find why and when it isn't working. 

For instance, with the same auth token(redacted here) - I made the following api calls in different iterations and pasting the results below.

```
https://developer-api.nest.com/structures 

https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/smoke_co_alarms

https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats
```

---

HttpRequest(https://developer-api.nest.com/structures, GET, ,List((auth, some_auth_token)),List((User-Agent, scalaj-http/1.0), (content-Type, application/json)),List(, , ), DIRECT, UTF-8, 4096,, true)

```
No Response
```

---

HttpRequest(https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/smoke_co_alarms, GET,  ,List((auth, some_auth_token)), List((User-Agent, scalaj-http/1.0), (content-Type, application/json)),List(, , ), DIRECT, UTF-8, 4096,, true)

[Json Response](https://jsonblob.com/5542e739e4b01638664051c1)

---

HttpRequest(https://developer-api.nest.com/structures, GET, , List((auth, some_auth_token)),List((User-Agent, scalaj-http/1.0), (content-Type, application/json)),List(, , ), DIRECT, UTF-8, 4096,, true)

[Json Response](https://jsonblob.com/5542e7b2e4b01638664051c2)

---

HttpRequest(https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats, GET,, List((auth, some_auth_token)),List((User-Agent, scalaj-http/1.0), (content-Type, application/json)),List(, , ), DIRECT, UTF-8, 4096,, true)

```
 No Response
```

---

I am fairly certain this is an issue with NEST API. Did anyone else face similar issues?

 What did you do or what do you suggest I try?

- I want to make REST API calls only - no firebase, etc
- CURL requests from terminal for the same works consistently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you use gist or pastebin? The format is hard to read.

From OP:

> I figured out the issue. I hadn't enabled the option to follow
>   temporary redirects and the null response was because I was only
>   extracting the body. I completely missed that I was extracting the
>   body content while printing the response

Comment: I hope this formatting helps. More than the actual response, I was trying to emphasize calling `structures` endpoint gets some response the second time, but not the first time in the above instance.

Comment: And both the home structures has at least 1 thermostat associated with it and I would expect some response for the `thermostat` api call

Comment: The responses that you got back look normal. I'm not sure why you would get no response. Even rate limits get an error code response, theres nothing that should just not respond. What are you using to make the calls? Can you reproduce easily?

Comment: I use https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http (Scalaj) to make http requests. As you would have noted from the above examples, the requests contain auth parameter(contained in 1st list) with header content (2nd list) and also the body content (3rd list). I tried playing with these options, but I am not sure why it fails in NEST's case while it works just fine while making requests to other API sources (other than NEST servers i.e).

Comment: Also, as soon I get a token by OAuthing, I make 4 API calls - to fetch structure/thermostat pairs(2 calls) and structure/protect pairs (2 calls). And every time, only 1 (rarely 2 or at times 0) request(s) result in proper responses and there is no pattern as to which one it is.
I do know that a single call would suffice in NEST's case but we do this to have generic way across few API sources that we cater to.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using if you are comfortable? I have yet to see a complaint about the API like this and I can't reproduce.

Comment: I figured out the issue. I hadn't enabled the option to follow temporary redirects and the null response was because I was only extracting the body. I completely missed that I was extracting the body content while printing the response.
Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Ha I probably just slowed you down :p